# Vue: can slot data go back to parent to pass down a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have my parent component using a `MyGrid` component and slotting in data.  Inside `MyGrid`, I am checking the `item` type and if it is a certain type, I am giving it a class `typeSquare`.
In the interest of keeping `MyGrid` "dumb", is there a way I can check the type and *then* have `MyGrid` pass in a prop for the class?

**Parent**

```
 <MyGrid
    :items="items"
    columnGap="12"
    rowGap="14"
   >
      <template v-slot="slotProps">
         <Cover
         v-if="slotProps.typename === 'NewOne'"
         :project="slotProps.item.data"
       />
         <Cover2 v-else-if="slotProps.typename != 'NewOne'" :project="slotProps.item.data"/>
   </template>
  </MyGrid>
```

---

**MyGrid.vue**

```
<template>
  <div :class="$style.root">
    <div :class="$style.gridContainer">
      <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div
          :key="index"
          :class="[{ [$style.gridItem]: true }, { [$style.typeSquare]: item.typename === 'NewOne' }]"
          :style="{
            padding: `${columnGap}px ${rowGap}px`,
          }"
        >
          <slot :item="item"></slot>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: So you want to pass only objects of a certain type from that list of "items"?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only pass items that are of a certain criteria you can filter them out using computed properties. In your script add computed object like so

```
   computed:{
      filteredItems(){
        return this.items.filter(item=>item.typename === 'NewOne')
      }
    },
```

And after in your template you can pass computed property instead of the whole list

```
 <MyGrid
    :items="filteredItems"
    columnGap="12"
    rowGap="14"
   >
```